Tuple Pick and Omit Utility
I am trying to create two utility types: PickTuple and OmitTuple. Opposed to the known Pick and Omit utilities working on objects it should work on tuples.
My own attempt at the PickTuple utility:
export type Indices<T extends any[]> = Exclude<
  keyof T,
  keyof any[]
> extends `${infer I extends number}`
  ? I
  : never;

type Tuple = [unknown, ...unknown[]]; 

type PickTuple<T extends Tuple, K extends Indices<T>> = {
  [P in K]: T[P];
};

type Example = [one: number, two: string];

type Result = PickTuple<Example, 1>; // => { 1: string }
// Why is the result an object ?

See playground.
I have found this code from @jcalz: comment.
It even preserves the tuple labels which is a prefered. It doesn't constraint the indices but that could be done with my Indices utility, I guess.
Would be great to have the counterpart OmitTuple type as well. While not neccessarly required, preserving the tuple labels would be great.
If it is consistent and reasonable, handling leading- / middle- / rest- and optional- tuples would be great as well, to make it truly versatile and reusable, but it is not a requirement for my use case.
Complexity is not an issue but an explanation would be usefull for understanding.
Short: I need a TuplePick and TupleOmit utility type.

• Please [edit] to change the names of your utility types not to collide with or shadow the original ones. It only makes things more confusing for everyone. Maybe PickTuple or OmitTuple or something? • Presumably your primary question isn't "why is the result an object?" from the code comment, but "how do I write my utility types", right? Please [edit] to make sure that the post asks a single clearly articulated question.

(see prev comment) Does this approach meet your needs? You say label preservation is a "bonus"; does that mean you're happier with a complicated answer which preserves labels instead of a simpler one which doesn't? My code preserves the labels but edge cases might happen. Do you care about open-ended tuples like [number, string, ...boolean[]]? Do you care about leading/middle rest tuples like [number, ...boolean[], string] or [...number[], boolean, string]? What about tuples with optional elements? The use cases matter. Please [edit] to clarify.

I have edited the question hope that answers all questions. Your approach looks very good! If you do answer maybe you could explain the use of the symbol as well, as that confuses me a bit. Thank you!

I think I need to see the use cases you care about as examples in the question. Not just mentioning them but actual examples, with what your expected outputs are, so I can test.  Like, you need to tell me what TupleOmit<[number, string, ...Date[], boolean], 3> should produce, if anything. And if you truly don't care about such inputs, then don't give an example and say "I don't need rest tuples to work".cOtherwise you're going to get multiple answers with different edge case behavior.

Okay I added a link. (Can't add it here as it's too long)
As you can see in my usecase its mostly limited to plain tuples with known elements (no spread & no optional fields). But to make it reusable it would be great to have it be able to handle those as well. I added a section at the end for my idea of what that would look like, you know better if it's reasonable or not.

• You can certainly put your use case examples here as plain text, with inputs and expected outputs, not just a link. I'm not saying to put everything in there, just "this goes in, this comes out", like at the bottom of your link. • I'm not sure how to weight the "reusable" aspect of this when it comes to providing a solution. My answer so far would preserve labels, but not behave as desired in your optional/rest cases. I just don't know how much effort to spend on trying to achieve these things.

Okay, I believe there is no way to index a spreaded tuple anyways, so I guess your current approach is sufficient. For my use case it is anyways. I do know how to include optional fields, by removing the optional modifier, like so: playground .
If you want to write an answer, feel free to do so.

Sure. The approach in my playground is to convert all elements to drop to a unique symbol I made up (since I know you will never use that in your tuples) and then filter by contents (since the indices change once you start filtering). If that seems to weird, I can do it this way instead where we attach the indices to the values like [A, B, C] becomes [['0',A],['1',B],['2',C]] and then filter those, and remove the indices. Any preference for which approach to expand upon in an answer?

Ahh, that makes sense! I still prefer the second approach, as it is more conventional and intuitive (to me at least). Thanks for the explanation!

Okay I'll write an answer when I get a chance, might not be for a number of hours.

There are lots of ways to approach this, although some of the details work better than others with certain use cases. Preserving tuple labels is possible but it's hard to combine this with optional tuple elements or rest elements in tuple types, especially leading or middle rest elements. Maybe it's not impossible, but it's more complex.
Anyway, the basic approach is to recognize that you are re-indexing the tuple. The Pick and Omit utility types always preserve the original keys of any property it keeps. If you have Pick<{"0": "a", "1": "b"}, "1"> you'll get {"1": "b"}. But with a tuple you would be unhappy if PickTuple<["a", "b"]> produced something like [undefined, "b"] or the hypothetical but invalid sparse tuple type [, "b"]; where the "b" is in the same 1 position and there's nothing in the 0 position. This is the problem you were running into... even if Pick on a tuple produced a tuple, it's unlikely to what you want.  This is sort of the subject of microsoft/TypeScript#40586; it would be nice if TypeScript provided some out-of-the-box way to filter tuples by index and then re-index them not to be sparse, but it doesn't.  So we have to build it.
The approach I'd take is to write a tuple filter, which I'll call TupleExtract<T, V> or TupleExclude<T, V> where you either filter in or out any tuple element whose type is assignable to V.  Then we just have to map the original tuple to one where the indexes we want to keep or discard get their values mapped to some value type. Then after that we can possibly re-map the tuple type. I'll define these later.
Let's come up with a concrete game plan for using these: we'll convert a type like ["a", "b", "c"] to a tuple where the indices are part of the values, like [["0","a"],["1","b"],["2","c"]. Then we can TupleExtract or TupleExclude anything that looks like [N, any] where N is the set of indices we care about. And finally remap the filtered tuple (say, [["1","b"],["2","c"]]) to discard the old indices (say, ["b", "c"])`.  It looks like this:
type MapWithIndex<T extends any[]> = { [I in keyof T]: [I, T[I]] }
type MapWithoutIndex<T extends any[]> = { [I in keyof T]: T[I][1] }

type PickTuple<T extends any[], N extends Indices<T>> =
    MapWithoutIndex<TupleExtract<MapWithIndex<T>, [`${N}`, any]>>

type OmitTuple<T extends any[], N extends Indices<T>> =
    MapWithoutIndex<TupleExclude<MapWithIndex<T>, [`${N}`, any]>>

Now we need to define TupleExtract. This is necessarily a recursive conditional type, and to improve performance we should make it tail-recursive. Maybe like this:
type TupleExtract<T extends any[], V, A extends any[] = []> =
    T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ?
    TupleExtract<R, V, F extends V ? T extends [...infer FF, ...R] ? [...A, ...FF] : [...A, F] : A> :
    A;

So we filter T to keep only those elements assignable to V, and use A as an accumulator.  We use variadic tuple types to split T into its first element F and the rest R. If this fails then we're done, and we return the accumulator. If this succeeds, we return a TupleExtract<R, V, NewA> where NewA is either [...A, F] (if F is assignable to V, because we want to keep it), or A (if F is not assignable to V, because we want to discard it).  The trick to preserving F's tuple label is to re-infer T against [...infer FF, ...R], with the intent that FF will become a one-element tuple containing F... and importantly, the same label as F has.  So then instead of [...A, F], we use [...A, ...FF] and keep the label.  If for some reason that check doesn't work then we just return [...A, F].  It's complicated, yes. That's unfortunate but you can't ask TypeScript to attach a label to some random element F that happened to come from a tuple. You need to actually get the piece of the original tuple.
Anyway, TupleExclude is identical except we reverse the sense of when to keep or discard an element:
 type TupleExclude<T extends any[], V, A extends any[] = []> =
    T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ?
    TupleExclude<R, V, F extends V ? A : T extends [...infer FF, ...R] ? [...A, ...FF] : [...A, F]> :
    A;

Let's test it out (assuming that Indices is already defined for us):
type Foo = [a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"]

type Bar = PickTuple<Foo, 1 | 2>;
//   ^? type Bar = [b: "b", c: "c"]

type Baz = OmitTuple<Foo, 1 | 2>;
//   ^? type Baz = [a: "a"]

type Example = [one: number, two: string];
type Result = PickTuple<Example, 1>;
//   ^? type Result = [two: string]

Looks good. The PickTuple and ExcludeTuple produce the expected values for these use cases.

And if you try them with optional or rest tuples they will most likely break. You might be able to futz with TupleExtract and TupleExclude to handle some of those cases, but it's more complicated and because you don't require this, I'm not inclined to go crazy trying.
Playground link to code

It took me a bit to digest this, but I always appreciate the extended research and work you put in. I love the links and explanations—they really help one learn how to solve things independently in the future! I also just realized that I can use TupleExclude and TupleExtract, which would have been my reasonable follow-up question, to filter tuples as well. love it. I probably need to read the whole documentation myself one day. Until then, I always appreciate your advice.

You can iterate a tuple and check the current index against the provided indices (tuple labels aren't preserved though):
Playground
export type Indices<T extends any[]> = Exclude<
  keyof T,
  keyof any[]
> extends `${infer I extends number}`
  ? I
  : never;

type Tuple = [unknown, ...unknown[]]; 

type PickTuple<T extends Tuple, N extends Indices<T>, R extends unknown[] = [], K extends number = N, P extends unknown[] = T> = 
  P extends [] ? [] : 
  [
      ...R['length'] extends K ? [T[R['length']]] : [], 
      ...P extends [unknown, ...infer B] ? PickTuple<T, never, [unknown, ...R], K, B> : []
  ]

type OmitTuple<T extends Tuple, N extends Indices<T>, R extends unknown[] = [], K extends number = N, P extends unknown[] = T> = 
  P extends [] ? [] : 
  [
      ...R['length'] extends K ? [] : [T[R['length']]], 
      ...P extends [unknown, ...infer B] ? OmitTuple<T, never, [unknown, ...R], K, B> : []
  ]


type Example = [one: number, two: string, three: boolean];

type Result = PickTuple<Example, 2|0>; // [number, boolean]
type Result2 = OmitTuple<Example, 0|2>; // [string]


Shadowing the existing Pick and Omit utility types is only going to make things more confusing for everyone. Please consider renaming them.

I like this. You could now edit the alias as well like @jcalz mentions, as I have edited my question now as well. This is clearly understandable! Thank you! Let's see what jcalz solution is and if it's more fitting.
